# how to call a method by using nstimer in background state

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to fetch service for every 15 mins,so i am using NSTimer.It is working fine.But how to call same service while app is in background state by using nstimer.Nstimer is not working in background state.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self sendBackgroundLocationToServer];
}


- (void) sendBackgroundLocationToServer
{
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
          beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
          }];


//Start Timer
[self startTimer];

//Close the task
if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}
}
```